# Hiding divs on small devices with Bootstrap 3.1.0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need some help in hiding text on all devices smaller than desktops and larger. I am using Bootstrap 3.1.0. The code I'm using is here [on CodePen.](http://codepen.io/LeeU/pen/NbZzYo)

Since mouses are not (usually) used on smaller devices to hover, I don't want the text in the `<span>` showing at all, just the links. When I use `@media(min-width: 992px)`, it works fine on the desktop but on smaller devices the text in the `<span>` displays on smaller devices instead of the links. Any idea what is wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/analysis/the-real-goal-of-the-meeting.php" class="more_info_news">
<span><strong>Summary:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit. Uterque enim summo bono fruitur, id est voluptate.
Ita ne hoc quidem modo paria peccata sunt.</span>The Real Goal of the Meeting</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media(min-width: 992px) {
    a.more_info_news {position:relative;z-index:24;color:#0F0FB6;text-decoration:none;}
    a.more_info_news:hover {z-index:25;background-color:#fff;}
    a.more_info_news span {display:none;font-size:small;text-decoration:none;}
    a.more_info_news:hover span {display:block;position:absolute;top:35px;width:350px;border:1px solid #000;background-color:#EDE9D3;color:#000;left:10px;visibility:visible;padding:5px;}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You presumably need to set a default style for the `span` (and possibly the anchor and other elements). The "default" being the mobile device. For example, outside of your media query:

```
a.more_info_news span {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great! But, just for my understanding, how does that work? I know what it does but, having placed it **after** (and outside) the media query, it still displays in anything larger than 992px.

Comment: In a word, "[specificity](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css+specificity)". The styles in the media query override the styles defined outside (that have less _specificity_). Personally, I would still include the default styles first - as that would seem to be the more logical order. Styles defined later only override the same or less specific styles (the _cascade_).

Comment: Ah, of course. I hadn't thought abut that. (BTW, I moved the default first.)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

There are built in CSS-classes in Bootstrap that does the same thing as the CSS in the answer by w3dk.

If you plan to continue to use Bootstrap 3.1.0; use the `visible` and/or `hidden` classes like so: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

However, in the Alpha of Bootstrap v4 there is a `.hidden-md-down`-class that would do the exact thing you were looking for. 
Example from the alpha:

```
`@media (max-width: 991px) {
   .hidden-md-down {
    display: none !important;
  }
}`
```

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

Answer (score 1):

When you using Bootstrap so you didn't need @media
You just need to use `.hidden-xs`  class to Hide div in Extra Small Devices like Mobile

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
.
.
.
</div>
```

Comment: you can Use '.hidden-ms' for hiding Div in Small Devices